# SCTP RCVBUF is not set properly in Linux

Tags: linux, sctp

I am trying to set RCVBUF to 1MB//1048576 , But after setting the value when I am trying to read it through getsockopt it always gives the value as 2MB//2097152
could anyone let me know what is the problem with the below code?

```
    unsigned int rcvBuf = getRcvBufValue();
    if (setsockopt (channelfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvBuf,sizeof (rcvBuf)) == -1) 
  {
         cout<<"RCV BUF IS NOT SET";
  }
      int rcvbuf = -1;
      socklen_t Rsize = sizeof(rcvbuf);
      getsockopt (channelfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF,&rcvbuf,&Rsize);
      cout<<rcvbuf;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what is said in `man 7 socket` regarding SO_RCVBUF option:

> **SO_RCVBUF**
>
> Sets or gets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes.
>   **The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping
>   overhead) when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this doubled value
>   is returned by getsockopt(2).** The default value is set by the
>   /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default file, and the maximum allowed value is
>   set by the /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max file. The minimum (doubled)
>   value for this option is 256.